# Is it possible to migrate Firefox XUL addon users to use a Firefox SDK addon instead?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I've just finished porting a Firefox XUL extension to Firefox SDK, in response to changes coming in a future version of Firefox that would completely break our legacy code. So far, however, I haven't managed to find any guides or documentation for how to migrate users from the older system to the newer one.

Pointing update.rdf to an xpi file generated by the Firefox SDK hasn't produced the desired affect, and simply dragging the xpi into the addon window creates a side-by-side installation.

Any tips on how to gracefully update users to the new architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not only possible, it's very simple: just copy the ID from the install.rdf of the XUL addin and paste it into the ID field of package.json in the SDK addon folder. From reading the docs, I was under the impression the format of the SDK addon ID mattered, looks like I was mistaken.